# Slider fica por cima do submenu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Gente, tudo bem?
Estou usando o nivo slider do jquery e fiz também um menu com submenus, porém quando passo o mouse em cima do menu para aparecer o submenu, esse slider do jquery fica por cima, o submenu que deveria ficar por cima do slider. Como faço para resolver isso ?

```
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="aux">
            <li>Home
                <ul>
                    <li>ddddddddd</li>
                    <li>ddddddddd</li>
                    <li>ddddddddd</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Empresa
                <ul>
                    <li> bbbbbbbbb
                        <ul>
                            <li>cccccccc</li>
                            <li>cccccccc</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li> bbbbbbbbb</li>
                    <li> bbbbbbbbb</li>
                    <li> bbbbbbbbb</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Clientes</li>
            <li>Contato</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div id="wrapper" class="b">
        <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
            <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                <img src="demo/images/on.jpg" data-thumb="demo/images/toystory.jpg"alt="" />
                <a href="http://dev7studios.com">
                    <img src="demo/images/up.jpg" data-thumb="demo/images/up.jpg" alt="" title="This is an example of a caption" />
                </a>
                <img
                    src="demo/images/binario.jpg" data-thumb="demo/images/walle.jpg" alt=""
                    data-transition="slideInLeft" />
                <img src="demo/images/nemo.jpg" data-thumb="demo/images/nemo.jpg"
                    alt="" title="#htmlcaption" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

coloca seu  (class="menu") como position relative, e adiciona um z-index alto (normalmente os menus sempre tem um z-index alto).

```
.menu { 
  position : relative;
  z-index : 99;
}
```

o que pode estar rolando, é como vc ta usando uma lib para fazer o slider, deve ter alguma propriedade dele sobrepondo o z-index default do nav, testa esse carinha e me fala se deu certo ou não.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve usar a propriedade z-index do css, mais não dá para te mostrar qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso, pois com esse código ai, não dá para saber o que você está usando. A porcentagem adequada pode variar conforme o caso, se for html puro, pode ser um número entre 3 e 20000, se não funcionar, inclua !important, agora, se você estiver usando algo como Bootstrap, tudo muda e provavelmente o z-index não será suficiente.

tente:

```
<style>
nav > .aux > li > ul{position: absolute; z-index: 20000:!important;}
</style>
```

isso será suficiente para força o submenu a sobrepor os demais elementos da pagina, ao mesmo tempo, isso também pode quebrar o seu design, cada caso é um caso, tem que se saber qual é o código problemático para se obter uma solução. Existem diferentes formas de se fazer isso.